# Insert spaces in equation in R Shiny application with mathjax

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, mathjax

I would like to make a shiny app where I display equations with Mathjax.  But they don't look good because there are no spaces put between any of the equation terms.  Here's my code with the equation inside the renderText statement.  I'm using the equation in Shiny, but am getting the mathjax code for rendering by putting the raw equation into an R Markdown document and using the mathml library's "mathout" function to produce the code for the equation in the function.  Perhaps that is what I am doing wrong.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
        title = 'MathJax Examples',
        uiOutput('ex3'))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
             output$ex3 <- renderUI({
             withMathJax(
             renderText("$${610.70}{\\cdot}{\\exp{\\left[{\\left({17.38}{{}} 
                        {ta}\\right)}{/}{\\left({239.00}{+}{ta}\\right)}\\right]}}$$"))
})}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The output looks like this:
610.70⋅exp[(17.38ta)/(239.00+ta)]

There are similar questions on Stackoverflow, I realize, but I can't get their suggestions to work.  I would like to get output that looks like this:

```
610.70 * exp[(17.38 * ta)/(239.00 + ta)]
```

I should add that I get an escape error if I use single backslashes.  If I do '\cdot' instead of '\cdot'. for example:

```
Error: '\c' is an unrecognized escape in character string 
(<input>:4:31)
```

Comment: Is `\\ ` not suitable?

Comment: The escape error when using a single backslash is normal. However, why is e.g. `\\ \\cdot \\ ` not suitable?

Comment: You have to be more specific and provide an example.  I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I understand your question such that you ask for how to insert spaces e.g. between the `\\cdot` such that it looks like `610.70 * exp` and not like `610.70*exp`. The command for such a space is two backslashes followed by one space, so you could use `610.70 \\ \\cdot \\ \\exp` in such a case.

Comment: OK, I see.  Is there any app or tool that would generate this for me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257197/discussion-between-user8229029-and-jan).

Comment: I don't understand. You need an app or tool to insert literal text in the middle of other literal text in your code? You could just do `sub("\\\\cdot", "\\\\ \\\\cdot \\\\", your_existing_string)`, or `gsub` if there are two or more `cdot`s.

Comment: Besides `"\\ "` (which produces backslash space), there are several other spacing commands in LaTeX for different sized spaces.  I think MathJax supports them.  For a list, see "Spacing Commands" in section 7 on this page:  https://latex-tutorial.com/latex-space/

Comment: This is for 250+ equations (some of which are 20+ times the size of the example I used), for way more strings than cdot, some of which are shown in my example, including spaces between all math symbols and values, etc.  I would like to make a Shiny app that shows equations in a nice format, rather than just text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly advise against manually fiddling with the spaces in a mathematical equation (unless you know exactly what you are doing): in general, MathJax knows better than you.

This means: remove *all* braces from your equation: they tell MathJax not to apply the regular spacing rules. Braces are only necessary for grouping of sub-expressions to override the usual operator precedence rules. This does not apply in your case.

Furthermore, it is generally advised to use `\middle/` instead of plain `/` to  render a solidus fraction — for the same reason as using `\left(…\right)` instead of plain `(…)` (although in your case it doesn’t make a difference). Alternatively, use `\frac{…}{…}` for a stacked fraction.

Compare (press <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> below to see the output):

```html
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>

Original:

$${610.70}{\cdot}{\exp{\left[{\left({17.38}{{}} 
                    {ta}\right)}{/}{\left({239.00}{+}{ta}\right)}\right]}}$$

Corrected:

$$
  610.70 \cdot \exp{\left[
    \left( 17.38 ta \right) \middle/
    \left( 239.00 + ta \right)
  \right]}
$$

Using stacked fraction:

$$
  610.70 \cdot \exp \frac{17.38 ta}{239.00 + ta}
$$
```

Comment: With the stacked fraction version, I get the following:  Error: unexpected '$' in:
"    withMathJax(renderText($".  I'm using this in Shiny, so maybe there's a difference in how this is being ran here.  I don't know - I'm learning here.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are wrapping all of your operators in braces, which tells MathJax not to apply normal spacing rules around them.  Don't do that, use `"\\cdot"` instead of `"{\\cdot}"`, etc.  For example, this version of your sample looks fine:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = 'MathJax Examples',
  uiOutput('ex3'))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$ex3 <- renderUI({
    withMathJax(
      renderText("$${610.70}\\cdot{\\exp{\\left[{\\left({17.38}* 
                        {ta}\\right)}{/}{\\left({239.00}+{ta}\\right)}\\right]}}$$"))
  })}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I get this:

[image: screenshot]

I think the braces around the numbers and around `ta` are unnecessary, but are harmless.

You said in a comment that you had 250+ equations. Doing these edits by hand would be tedious, but if you have them in text somewhere, you could follow the suggestion of @r2evans and use `gsub()` on the file.  For example, if the equations are in the character variable `lines`, this would fix all the `\\cdot`, "+" and "*" operators:

```
lines <- gsub("{\\cdot}", "\\cdot", lines, fixed = TRUE)
lines <- gsub("{+}", "+", lines, fixed = TRUE)
lines <- gsub("{*}", "*", lines, fixed = TRUE)
```